# Can req.ip be faked in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ip, spam-prevention

I am trying to implement some anti-spamming mechanism into my server. I need to know whether req.ip can be faked by the remote hacker in Express.js. Could someone please confirm this with me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be faked. `request.ip` getting it's value from the left most entry of the X-Forwarded-For header, which can be faked.

Express docs:
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.ip

Comment: ok...then is there a way to obtain the real ip which can't be faked?

Comment: Well, if you're not behind a proxy, you may try to check for the remote address of the connection itself (`request.connection.remoteAddress`). It's harder to spoof.

Comment: I don't see the documentation for request.connection. Is it deprecated?

Comment: Nope. it's in the node.js docs. 
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/http.html#http_request_socket
Also can be accessed as `request.socket` :)

Comment: What if you are behind a proxy and you want to obtain the real IP which can't be faked?