# Is it safe to whitelist an IP address using req.ip in express, node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, whitelist, websecurity

I want to whitelist access to a section of my website to only work for requests coming from a specific IP address. Is it safe to filter by IP address using `req.ip`? Is there an alternate best practice for things like this?

Example:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.ip !== "x.x.x.x") {
    return res.status(403).send();
  }
  next();
});

app.get("/whitelist", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("content");
});

app.listen(3000, "localhost", () => {
  console.log("Server is up");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not enough. [The IP of the request can be faked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165923/can-req-ip-be-faked-in-express-js). If someone gets ahold of your source code, and if they cared enough, they'll be able to access the restricted route.

Require a password (or *some* way of authenticating) instead.